# Installing php extension with yum

Tags: linux, yum, php-fpm, installation, php

I'm very new to Linux and yum. I need to install a php extension ([ioncube loader](http://www.ioncube.com/loader_installation.php)) using yum, but I'm not sure how exactly this is done. I'm going off [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/yum-command-examples/), which tells me I need to run the command

```
yum install <package>
```

or

```
yum install ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

in my case. I'm confused though as to where I need to put this file for yum to pick it up, if I still need to modify the php.ini file.. really I'm confused about everything. Can someone give me step by step instructions on how to do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: The yum command operates on packages, not individual .so files. The file you install will end in `.rpm`, which designates it as an RPM package. Do you have an RPM package, or just the .so file?

Comment: I only have the .so file. But this was done on a previous server of ours by a 3rd party sys admin. He wrote to me "We tend to install php components via yum repositories whenever possible to stay abreast of updates to software components in the stack. To that end, I installed ionCube from the iUS repository which maintains the php components we use in Magento deployment." I'm trying to repeat this process for our new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you need to do is find the iUS repo file and install it. A Google search turns this up: http://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html#release-packages. Install the `epel-release` and `ius-release` packages. After that, you need to figure out the package name, which I'm going to guess will be `ionCube` or something similar, and run `yum install` against it.

Answer (score 0):

You generally dont point yum at a file, but at a package name. For example:

```
yum search php
```

Will search the repos for the phrase php. You will get many results.

A typical usage to install php and zend for example:

```
yum install php-5.4-gd-zend-server.x86_64
```

Now, I've had a quick scan for installing ioncube via yum, but there doesn't seem to much about. Most of the pages I came across tell you how to install from source. Its certainly worth checking to see if there is a package available in some other repo, in which case you will need to add that repo to your yum config. And while I hate to do this, it is a case of hitting the docs (obviously these arent the official yum docs):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel5-fedora-core-add-new-yum-repository.html

Just one final note about yum and files. You may be able to find the package you want by issuing:

```
yum whatprovides <filename>
```

Which will tell you what package provides the file you have given.

Good luck

Comment: `yum provides` tells you what a given package provides - to find the package that provides what you're looking for, you have to use `yum whatprovides`